# Edit pivot table chart in google data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am creating a pivot table chart in Google Data Studio for user retention.

I am struggling with editing the style of the graph.

Here is how the graph looks like:

[image: -s]

I would like to:

1. remove the table header. (saying "period_after_acquisition / act_users")
2. Center the dimension label (1, 2, 3... identifying the "periods_after_acquisition" aka the first purchase)

I looked into chart > pivot table > style panel but it doesn't seem possible to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Headers**
Can be hidden by setting both the header components to blend in with the background, for example, if the background is White in colour:

- ***Header Font Colour***: White
- ***Header Background Colour***: White

**2) Alignment**
Currently not implemented in [Pivot Tables](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7516660) although alignment is implemented in [Tables](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044). One approach in a Table would be to use individual [CASE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c8104fdd-73ca-4647-a89a-e8fc1d22c1c2) and GIF to elaborate on the Headers:

[image]